# How do I create a thread that makes changes to a label in my CLR application?

Tags: clr

I apologize if my question is too comprehensive:

I have experience with visual c++ and Qt and I know how to do this in those environments but for the sake of the team, I need to make a CLR application.

I have a CLR Application as follows:

CLR application with a label element. (Unable to post images due to new account).

My requirement:

- I want to create a thread that changes the "Status here" label to display a simple string of data.
- The reason for this is: I have another c++ based client application which sends data through a named pipe to this application.
- My goal is to make a separate thread for this GUI form which does blocking connects and reads from the client and displays the data in a tabular form in this form.
- What I want to do is to know how I can modify items in the form after receiving the data from the pipe
- What kind of threads should I use, should I use the CLR thread pool or create a thread using System::Threading as follows:

  ```
  ThreadStart^ pTOperation = gcnew ThreadStart(startPipe);
  Thread^ pipeThread = gcnew Thread(pTOperation);
  pipeThread->Start();
  ```

where my startPipe operation is going to perform the functions of creating a server pipe, connecting with the client, doing reads and modifying the GUI elements. 
Does CLR have restrictions for modifying the main form elements from another thread like Qt does. (I had to implement a signal/slot system for that).

my idea: Can I pass an argument to the thread function that is a pointer to the forms label and change it's properties inside the thread function?

Comment: It isn't any different from native C++, a window should only be updated by the thread that created it.  The only difference is that you'll be reminding when you do it wrong in a managed program, that throws an InvalidOperationException.  You'll get a million google hits when you query for the exception message, most will tell you what to do about it.

Comment: Allright, so I need to update the form label only through the thread of the window. the main thread. 
Is this what I need to do?

- fork thread for named pipe communication
- send an argument or some sort of signal to the main thread to change the label's text using this string argument, every time a message is received.